# How can I remove the recently used programs on Windows Mobile 2003

Tags: settings

I have a PDA running Windows Mobile 2003.

Every time a program is used, it shows up in the recently used section of the start menu.

[image: Start Menu]

I have a program that saves the device registry state so I can keep things like WiFi configured when the PDA goes through a cold boot.
I'd like to remove these items from the start menu before I save the registry state so they aren't restored after a cold boot. The fact that they are implies that these entries are stored somewhere in there.

There's no option in the GUI to accomplish this.

How can I remove these items?

Comment: **Warning to readers:** [The current FAQ](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/faq) states that Windows Mobile is on-topic. Disagree? [Discuss on meta.](http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Per the current state of the Meta discussion, WM questions appear to be off topic  http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/13/is-windows-mobile-on-topic

Answer (score 2):

1. Move the stuff out of `\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
    using a file explorer.
2. Soft reset your Windows Mobile, such that it wipes any cache.
3. Move the stuff back into `\Windows\Start Menu\Porgarms`.

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience doing this myself but found two options from this [forum link](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/23105-36-clear-recently-programs-start-menu).

1. A third party application, such as `wisbar advance` has the option to turn the
   recent programs off.
2. Use a registry editor and go to \HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Shell. Delete TaskSwitch Key (and all subkeys/values) and soft reset IMMEDIATELY. Don't even close your reg editor. This is also shown [here](http://www.pocketpcfaq.com/raj/ClearRecent.html).

Comment: or do what @Tom Wijsman said. Sounds easier.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain but it could be possible that WM6 has a built-in registry editor which can be accessed by holding the action button (in between the arrows) and then clicking on the analog clock / digital time, then a context menu with two entries opens up. One of them is `Run`, in which one can type `regedit`. I feel like both methods are equally in complexity. *If it isn't three, install any registry editor you can find...*